# JList appears empty after adding one Object

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have a JList (=LstIncredients) in a JScrollPane (=spList), that contains String-Representations of an Object (=Incredients). I can "add" and "delete" these Incredients and can load or save them to Harddisk. At start the saved List (ArrayList) will be loaded vom HD and correctly shown in the Jlist.
**The Problem:** If i delete some and add some other all works fine, but if i add one more than there where at beginning, the JList is shown as completely empty. If i save and restart the program, only then all Incredients inclusive that i have added are shown correctly.

Code from ActionListener Button to add and delete an Incredient + Code from ListModel:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            switch (e.getActionCommand()) {
            case "add":
                System.out.println("add"); //for debug only
                Incredient i=getIncredientFromBoxes(); //Generates new Incredient from textboxes
                Incredient.addIncredient(i); //adds an Incredient to Incredient-ArrayList
                LstIncredients.repaint();
                break;
            case "del":
                System.out.println("del");
                Incredient iDel = getIncredientFromBoxes();
                Incredient.delIncredient(iDel);
                LstIncredients.repaint();

                break; ...

ListModel<String> incredientsModel = new ListModel<String>() {

        @Override
        public int getSize() {
        String pattern = txtName.getText(); // pattern is for filtering the Incredients-Array-List
            System.out.println("ListModel.getSitze: "+Incredient.getList(pattern).size()); //for debugging. Incredient-Class works fine 
            return Incredient.getList(pattern).size(); //returns a ArrayList
        }

        @Override
        public String getElementAt(int index) {
            String pattern = txtName.getText(); // filter for shown incredients
            System.out.println("getElement at: "+index); //for debugging
            return Incredient.getList(pattern).get(index).toString();

        }
```

If "public int getSize()" is larger than size at the begin, "public String getElementAt(int index)" isnt even called.

Maybe someone can help me?

Comment: I would guess your implement of the ListModel is causing problems I see no reason to create a custom ListModel, just use the DefaultListModel.

Comment: I suspect the list's new element data need to be added to the model. Where is that code?

Comment: List models are supposed to send events about the changes. If you were doing this correctly, there was no need for the `repaint` calls. But using the `repaint` calls  instead of propert event notification is not sufficient for updating the `JList`’s status.

Comment: @Holger: The point is: if i have f.e. 100 Items in my JList, i can delete and add and do whatever i want, everything is fine. But if there are 101+ Items in it, it the JList becomes empty. When i save it, close the application, restart and load these 101 Items from HDD, then all 101 are shown, and it only becomes empty when i add no. 102. There seems to be a limit to a max number of items when initialising the ListModel or JList, but i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: `There seems to be a limit to a max number of items when initialising the ListModel or JList` - the limit would be the maximum value of an int variable since methods of the model use int fields as parameters. `i don't know how to fix it.` - I already gave you a suggestion.

Comment: @Andrew Thompsen: Thx for help, im new here and new to java. Next time i'll be better!

Comment: Now i got it. Changed to DefaultListModel like camickr said and it works fine!

Comment: *"Changed to DefaultListModel like camickr said and it works fine!"* Another job done, @camickr.